# The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

```
 public class Bar
    {
        [Key]
        public int BarID { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal? DailyTotal { get; set; }
        public int PricelistID { get; set; }
        public virtual Pricelist Pricelist { get; set; }
    }

//in the BarController Create method

bar.DailyTotal = db.Bars.Sum(x => x.UnitTotal);
```

Comment: What is the question here ? What do you want ? What do you get ?

Comment: make unitTotal nullable: ``decimal? UnitTotal``

Answer (score 0):

It would suggest that you have a null in the `UnitTotal` column in your DB. You could either eliminate the null or change the type to be `decimal?`